Sitecore Context Site Name coming as null in SItecore Preprocessor
I am trying to extend Sitecore preprocessor Language.AlwaysstripLanguage but here in processor Sitecore.context is coming as null.
How to get current sitename in sitecore preprocessor pipelines.

You don't have a site name at this point. This processor runs in the preProcess pipeline, which is before any site and item resolution has taken place.

try Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextFactory -
using Sitecore.Sites;

public void GetCurrentSiteName()
{
    var siteContext = SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext();
    string currentSiteName = siteContext?.Name;
    // Use the current site name as needed
}


Site context is not available inside the preprocessRequest pipeline. It is set inside the httpRequestBegin pipeline that runs after preprocessRequest` pipeline, hence the site context is null.
However, you can use below code snippet to get the site context name inside the custom strip language processor created in the preprocessRequest pipeline.
using Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest;
using Sitecore.Sites;
using Sitecore.Web;
using System.Linq;

public class CustomStripLanguage : PreprocessRequestProcessor
{
  public override void Process(PreprocessRequestArgs args)
  {
     var hostName = args.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;
     SiteInfo site = SiteContextFactory.Sites
                .Where(s => s.RootPath != "" & s.HostName.Contains(hostName))
                .FirstOrDefault();
     if(site != null)
     {
        SiteContext contextSite =  SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext(site.Name);
     }
   }
}

Using above way, you should be successfully able to fetch site name inside preprocessRequest pipeline.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
